# unitary diagonlization in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

is there a built-in function or made already code in mathematica that computes a unitary diagonlization of a given matrix?

I.e, if the matrix is: A then I want to find P and D such that:

A=P* D P , where PP* = I, and * is the complex conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a matrix does in general not exist. Only normal matrices (commuting with their own transpose/adjoint) can be diagonalized with orthogonal transformations. For the others the best you can get is that D is upper triangular. See Smith normal form and real Smith normal form. The eigen-decomposition algorithms just produce this kind of normal form.

Comment: So for matrices that are normal, is there a already an existsed code to compute its unitary diagonilization?

Comment: As I said, this is precisely what all algorithms derived from the Francis QR algorithm do. One has to make the extra effort to accumulate the rotations from all iterations, this is often not done in the basis variant of the algorithm.